# How to find the column type in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

Does anyone know the best way in SPFx to find the type of a column in a list or document library?
I mean if it's a "Single line of text" "Date and Time" "Choice" "Hyperlink or Picture" etc
Thanks
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do this using PnPjs: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/fields/

ex:

```
  const fieldInfo = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List1").fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("FieldName")();
  console.log(fieldInfo .TypeDisplayName)
```